# Table Alignment Issues HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how this is going to work because, it is not a live website, it is a dashboard that pulls data from a chemical analysis program and give a browser view of it. My issue is I have two tables I need aligned at the top of the page. One aligned to the left and one centered. Right now I have a table with an image logo.gif aligned center then below it I have a table meaning/symbol headers aligned to the left I need those on the same line can anyone show me what to do? I can email a picture if need to be see what it looks like. I know there is a lot of broken tags, but I inherited this and it all works except for the two tables on top.

```
<div align="center">
<table border="0" width="800" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" >
<tr>
    <td height="60" width="100%"><p align="center"><img border="0"                  src="../Images/Logo.jpg" width="199" height="101"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#808080"  align="center" valign="top">
    <TABLE BORDER=2 width="23%" align="left" id="BodyTable" height="20"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000">
    <TR> <TH>Meaning</TH>              <TH>Symbol</TH> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>No Schedule</TD>      <TD align="center"><img  src='../Images/Not- ScheduledMain2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Deactivated Tanks</TD>     <TD align="center"><img   src='../Images/Gray-Astris2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test Scheduled</TD>      <TD align="center">    <img  src='../Images/BlueTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test In Process</TD> <TD align="center"><img  src='../Images/GreenTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test Late</TD> <TD align="center"> <img  src='../Images/RedTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD></TR>
<tr>
</TABLE>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#808080" align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="HeaderTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" height="73">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="34"><p align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="5">IEC's TrueLogic Dashboard</font></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="39"><p align="center">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="340" width="110%" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark ="#808080" align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="BodyTable" height="20" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
                <td height='20' width='20' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='360' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Process Line</b></td>
<!--   Sample Item Removed      <td height='10' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Sample</b></td>
-->                 <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Test Status</b></td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Adds</b></td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Corrective Action</b></td>
            </tr>
        </Table>
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="BodyTable" height="37" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript">[ItemsHTML]
            </script>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td HEIGHT="25"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td height="25">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table1">
            <tr>
        </tr>
                <td width="335"><p align="left"><font size="1"> <p> By TrueLogic Company <p> Edited By International Electronic Components</font></td>
                <td width="290"><p align="center"></td>
                <td width="135"><p align="right"><font size="1">[LastBuild]</font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td HEIGHT="25"></td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pls produce a fiddle next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
<div align="center">
<table border="0" width="800" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top" >
<tr>
    <td height="60" width="100%" align="center">
        <TABLE style="float:left;" BORDER=2 width="23%" align="left" id="BodyTable" height="20"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#000000">
    <TR> <TH>Meaning</TH>              <TH>Symbol</TH> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>No Schedule</TD>      <TD align="center"><img  src='../Images/Not- ScheduledMain2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Deactivated Tanks</TD>     <TD align="center"><img   src='../Images/Gray-Astris2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test Scheduled</TD>      <TD align="center">    <img  src='../Images/BlueTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test In Process</TD> <TD align="center"><img  src='../Images/GreenTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD> </TR>
    <TR> <TD><b>Test Late</TD> <TD align="center"> <img  src='../Images/RedTest2.png' width='20' height='22' align='center'></TD></TR>
<tr>
</TABLE>
        <img border="0" src="../Images/Logo.jpg" width="199" height="101">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="100%" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark="#808080" align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="HeaderTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" height="73">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="34"><p align="center"><b><font face="Arial" size="5">IEC's TrueLogic Dashboard</font></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" height="39"><p align="center">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="340" width="110%" bordercolorlight="#FFFFFF" bordercolordark ="#808080" align="center" valign="top">
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="BodyTable" height="20" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
                <td height='20' width='20' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='360' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Process Line</b></td>
<!--   Sample Item Removed      <td height='10' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Sample</b></td>
-->                 <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Test Status</b></td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Adds</b></td>
                <td width='14'>&nbsp;<td>
                <td height='20' width='120' bgcolor="#C0C0C0" ><p align='center'><a><b>Corrective Action</b></td>
            </tr>
        </Table>
        <table border="0" width="100%" id="BodyTable" height="37" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top">
            <script type="text/javascript">[ItemsHTML]
            </script>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td HEIGHT="25"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td height="25">
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table1">
            <tr>
        </tr>
                <td width="335"><p align="left"><font size="1"> <p> By TrueLogic Company <p> Edited By International Electronic Components</font></td>
                <td width="290"><p align="center"></td>
                <td width="135"><p align="right"><font size="1">[LastBuild]</font></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td HEIGHT="25"></td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One quick question the logo.gif is a little too far to the right now do I move it closer to the center?